# Does WinRT access the NT kernel directly (when it needs OS support) or does it go through Win32?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How is WinRT implemented beneath the hood?  Uses NT directly kernel directly or is it implemented on top of Win32/64?

Comment: Not sure what programming problem this question solves. It's implemented the same way as Win32 OS features are implemented. I believe this was stated multiple times at the //build keynotes.

Comment: God forbid you actually have some understanding of the system you are using... :-P  At least me it helps while programming, to have some idea of how the system works.

Comment: And according to @LarryOsterman below it's not ONLY implemented the same way as Win32 features are implemented, it's a bit of both.

Comment: Um, Win32 is also written with parts that talk to kernel services and parts that talk to other parts of Win32. It's a bit of both.

Comment: Raymond's comment is 100% correct.  He and I are saying the exact same thing - parts of Win32 are written directly on kernel services and parts aren't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both - some parts of the Windows runtime are new top-to-bottom (and thus interact directly with kernel services), other parts of the Windows runtime (WinRT) use existing services in Windows.

Comment: I'm eagerly awaiting more truthful architecture diagrams that show the actual dependencies among the various application API stacks.

Comment: I'm not sure that any of that matters (architectural diagrams showing the actual dependencies).

Comment: Maybe not, for me the most interesting thing was that WinRT is not managed .NET.

Comment: Watch the //build keynotes - the presenters made it *very* clear that the windows runtime was unmanaged - it's accessible from .Net but it is not .Net.

Comment: @Bob I think it would count as an implementation detail. Today some of it is on top of Win32, tomorrow is something else - why would the API client actually care?

Comment: I think this has become another point of confusion for the press, like the one conflating Win32 and x86. The only issue here is clarity, in the interest of defusing ongoing and pointless discussion by having the facts stated by those who know. I would hope devs know IE, CLR, etc. do not bypass Win32 either, but those diagrams gave people other ideas.