# WinRT and Win32 Interoperability

Tags: windows-runtime

Using Boost (1.48.0), vc 9.0 built, I have developed a Server.  Then exposed that Server functionality as Win32 DLL and loaded that DLL in MetroStyle App that runs on WinRT platform.  And the Server runs well.

My question is why the MetroStyle app is not having any problem for Loading win32 dll?

How Win32 server is working well with WinRT environment?

How WinRT and Win32 inter operability works?

Comment: WinRT currently is only an api layer on top of win32.  Your luck will run out when you try to submit your program to the store or when you try to run it on a pad with an arm core.

Comment: @HansPassant WinRT is not an API layer on top of Win32. WinRT is a new set of APIs running along side a subset of Win32 API available on the Metro side.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by Server functionality? A subset of Win32 is still supported on Metro. WinRT and Win32 are both native code and a separate set of APIs hence they should work seamlessly together.

Comment: @iaimtomisbehave At this moment WinRT *is* built on top of Win32 (as of Windows Developer Preview). Internally it calls Win32, but it is just an implementation detail and will change in the future. Conceptually they are two independent alternatives.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254988/does-winrt-access-the-nt-kernel-directly-when-it-needs-os-support-or-does-it-g